# How to solve Keycloak POST request problem?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm using keycloak to protect my restapi endpoints. I have a permission bot /bonuses/* permission and i can get result 200 for GET /bonuses/list endpoint.

But I'm getting an unauthorized errors for POST /bonuses/create endpoint.

I guess there is a restriction for POST request but I couldn't find it yet.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I realized the problem, because of crsf is enabled. How can i configure CRSF ?